# Registering a dependency in ASPNET Core with TWO different lifetime scopes

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, .net-core

I joined a team recently that has a lot of existing code. This code has been written by many different people over the past couple of years.

Extensions methods have been created off of the `IServiceCollection` to make registering dependencies easier. While I was digging around the inner workings of some of the code, I saw the following was done in two different extension methods.

**Extension 1**

```cs
public void AddServices1(this IServiceCollection services)
{
   services.AddScoped<IService, Service>();
}
```

**Extension 2**

```cs
public void AddServices2(this IServiceCollection services)
{
   services.AddTransient<IService, Service>();
}
```

In the `Startup.cs` file the following exists

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
   ...
   services.AddServices1();
   ...
   ...
   services.AddServices2();
   ...
}
```

What I would like to understand what the impact is of registering a service as two different lifetimes?

I've done a lot of Googling but I can't find anyone that talks about what happens when a service is registered twice, but with different lifetimes. How does the Kestrel DI decide which lifetime type to use when resolving this service.

My best guess would be that it basically uses the last registered one - and the first one is thrown away, but I am not sure if that is 100% correct.

Does anyone know the exact workings of this?

Comment: Unless there something you're not showing us, the system will inject the most recently added implementation of `IService`, in this case, the one added in `AddServices2`. This is very unusual and I would flag it up with the team you have joined.

Comment: @DavidG this is exactly why I'm asking. It is something that I would like to raise with the team, but I just wanted to understand what the implications of doing it this way would be. Because the problem is, in some other micro-services that I've seen, `AddServices2` would be called before `AddServices1` which would then result in different behaviour. Thank you for confirming my thoughts.

Comment: If it's being used differently in different places, that, in my opinion, is even worse as now you have inconsistent behaviour.

Comment: Exactly! Now that I understand more, I can take this up to the team lead and we can fix this what I can imagine is only a mistake. I don't think that the service needs to be registered in both these extension methods. If it is required for more than one, it should be in it's own extension method. I'll be able to tell the team lead that we need to fix this now.

Comment: maybe you need to use `TryAddScoped` which only adds the service if it has not been added before

Comment: @Kahbazi you are correct. That would different solve this issue. All I need to do is figure out which is the actual intended lifetime that is wanted and then we can do `TryAdd` instead, which will completely solve the problem :)

Comment: I'm calling XY problem on this one. It makes no sense to have the same service in two different lifetimes. The lifetime is an inherent quality of a class, based on its needs and what it does. If you have two different lifetimes, your class is either not specialized enough (doing too much) and/or you don't understand what lifetime it should actually be created in. Why is that you think you need two different lfietimes in the first place?

Comment: @ChrisPratt you are correct. It is something that I don't like to see either though, but that is why I had originally posted the question. I need us to get a proper usage of this service across all the different microservices that make use of it.

Comment: That may be your issue. Microservices shouldn't really be sharing anything. That's kind of the point. They should be self-contained and discreet units of functionality. If you're bleeding logic between microservices, you haven't properly subdivided your domain.

Comment: This registration is a code smell commonly referred to as an [Ambiguous Lifestyle](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ambiguouslifestyles.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right you will get the latest registered services when you use `serviceProvider.GetService<IService>();`, but keep this in mind that you can also get both of them with `serviceProvider.GetService<IEnumerable<IService>>();` and in this case each one has its own lifestyle.